# Menu Text disappears after resizing from Mobile to Desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very simple menu system on my website: http://jsfiddle.net/r7zv2o97/

When I resize the window down to Mobile size, a button appear - great!

When I click this button it hides the menu - great!

**However**, when I resize the window back up to Desktop size the word `Menu` doesn't appear again.

How do I fix this?

```js
$('#header_nav').prepend('<div id="menu-button"></div>');

$('#menu-button').on('click', function(){
    var menuItems = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
    menuItems.toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
    background:black;
}

#header_nav {
  padding-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  transition: height .001s ease;
  background: #1588cb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#menu-button {
  display:none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.menu-primary-menu-container {
    display:inline-block
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {

  #menu-button {
    display: block;
    top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px 0px 22px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #menu-button:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 16px;
  }

  #menu-button:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 26px;
  }

  #menu-button.active {
      
  }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_nav">

<nav class="primary menu">

    <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
        
        <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="/wordpress/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    
</nav>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**:

When you hide `.menu-primary-menu-container` in small devices and after that resize the windows. It has `display:none;` so you can not see `.menu-primary-menu-container`. However, the below code override js `display:none;` where window size is higher than `420px`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7zv2o97/2/)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
    .menu-primary-menu-container {
        display:inline-block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: So so sorry for my delay. Real life getting in the way. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mq4un5rd/)

```js
$('#header_nav').prepend('<div id="menu-button"></div>');

$('#menu-button').on('click', function () {
    var menuItems = $(".menu-primary-menu-container");
    menuItems.toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
body {
    background:black;
}
#header_nav {
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    transition: height .001s ease;
    background: #1588cb;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#menu-button {
    display:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.menu-primary-menu-container {
    display:inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    #menu-button {
        display: block;
        top: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 0px 22px 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #111;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #menu-button:after {
        display: block;
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
        right: 20px;
        top: 16px;
    }
    #menu-button:before {
        display: block;
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        height: 3px;
        width: 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
        right: 20px;
        top: 26px;
    }
    #menu-button.active {
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 420px) {
    .menu-primary-menu-container {
        display:inline-block !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="header_nav">
    <nav class="primary menu">
        <div class="menu-primary-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-primary-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-44"><a href="/wordpress/">Home</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```